# Can .NET Reflection "reflect" on a running system?

Tags: .net, reflection, methods, excel-dna

Context: Windows 7, Office 2007, ExcelDNA 0.30

Given that ExcelDNA doesn't support ParamArray, I had an outlandish idea: can Reflection help?

After a bit of fiddling with .NET and Reflection I can see that it's good at getting static info about an Assembly, even down to the the names and data types of methods. However (and I don't know where to go to find this out) can it tell me stuff about a system as it is running?

For instance, can I know how many arguments were actually supplied to a method that has 30 parameters (named p1 through p30) or do I have to do a long select case checking each (as I do now without Reflection)? Can I access the arguments iteratively, from 1 to the number of "occupied" parameters?

And on a related issue: I can pass two arguments to a method defined with three parameters, but I can't pass three arguments to a method defined with two. Is there a way of defining a method to receive any number of parameters, but **without** using ParamArray (remember, we're using ExcelDNA here, which doesn't support ParamArray)?

Comment: Are you going to use the info to make programmatic decisions or are you just debugging?

Comment: @BitOff: To make programmatic decisions. Debugging is not in the viewfinder.